# draw a stroke around the shape, core graphic

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, drawrect

I am drawing a shape like following :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Draw a cross rectagle
    CGContextRef    context     =   UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 190, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 220, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310, 90);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310, 120);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

I am getting a light-dark cross flag below

[image]

Now I would like to draw a stroke around the cross flag I have just drawn

What should I do to achieve this. Please advice me on this issue. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely `CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);` is what you're after

You can adjust the pattern and color using:

```
CGContextSetStrokePattern
CGContextSetStrokeColor
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html

So, in your case, assuming you want a plain black stroke, you'd have:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef    context     =   UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 190, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 220, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310, 90);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310, 120);
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Produces:

[image: Reminds me of Kraftwork! Result of drawRect:]

Comment: I have just added these lines `CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);`.However, it does not work. I am sure I am missing something in the middle. Do you have any idea about it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Draw a cross rectagle
    CGContextRef    context     =   UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    //New
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 190, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 220, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310, 90);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310, 120);

    //New
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    //New
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

@WDUK :after spending hours to figure it out, I know why your above answer is not working. 
The reason is when you do `CGContextFillPath` first, the path is eventually cleared and then you  can no long do `CGContextStrokePath` on it again. 
Therefore in order to do `CGContextFillPath` and `CGContextStrokePath`, we have to do

> ```
> CGContextDrawPath(context,  kCGPathFillStroke);
> ```

After trying it , I am getting the following

[image]

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working! Do you want me to update my answer for this?

Comment: Edit done, with screenshot of what I get when I run it. Thanks again :)